# VueJs Checked Radio Button group

Tags: vue.js

I am using vueJs and have a radio button group. When the radio is checked how can I bind a css border attribute to a class `:class="selected"`?

The `:checked` attribute does not work as I have bound it to the v-model.

So if the radio is checked bind a class (selected) to the div.

```
<div class="sau-select lg center" :class="selected">
   <label for="windows">
      <input type="radio" id="windows" value="windows" v-model="selectedOs" :checked="checked">
      <span></span>
      <img src="/img/windows.gif" alt="Windows">Windows
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the name of the class?

Comment: .selected, I've updated question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:class="selected"` you use hasn't much effect.

To conditionally apply a class to the `div`, you will have to use as `:class` condition if the `selectedOs` equals the `value` attribute of each `<input>`, such as `:class="{redborder: selectedOs === 'windows'}"`. More details in the demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedOs: 'windows'
  }
})
```

```css
.redborder { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label :class="{redborder: selectedOs === 'windows'}">
    <input type="radio" value="windows" v-model="selectedOs"> Windows
  </label>

  <label :class="{redborder: selectedOs === 'linux'}">
    <input type="radio" value="linux" v-model="selectedOs"> Linux
  </label>
</div>
```

Notice that `value="linux"` means that that radio box will assign the string `"linux"` to the `v-model` variable (in this case `selectedOs`). `value="linux"` is equivalent to `:value="'linux'"`, for instance.

Comment: Do I need the :checked="checked" in both inputs?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference, so, no. To control if they are checked or not, the value of `selectedOs` should match each respective `value` attribute or not.